# gmaven no test found

Tags: unit-testing, maven-2, groovy, gmaven-plugin

Hi i m running into some error
I have a really small project in groovy.
I want to use maven.
I was able to compile my files, source and test(i have my .class in the target folder). But no test are executed.
here is my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>gmedia</groupId>
<artifactId>gmedia.api</artifactId>
<name>Gmedia API project</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
      <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc-5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <!--<goal>generateStubs</goal>-->
                      <goal>compile</goal>
                      <!--<goal>generateTestStubs</goal>-->
                      <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://ftp.ing.umu.se/mirror/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        <id>eclipselink</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

My groovy files are in  src/groovy and test/groovy

What i'm dooing wrong?

BTW, I get compilation errors when I add this configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <sources>
        <fileset>
            <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
            </includes>
        </fileset>
    </sources>
</configuration>
```

---

compile my file with erro when adding this to the groovy-maven-plugin

```
<configuration>
          <sources>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: compile my file with erro when adding this to the groovy-maven-plugin

<configuration>
          <sources>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
          </sources>
        </configuration>

Comment: not as a comment, edit the question text (did that for you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for one thing you are using an outdated version of GMaven.

The plugin has moved to the Group Id `org.codehaus.gmaven` and the current version is `1.3`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also, you probably need to keep the stub goals active for JUnit to find you test classes.

See this page for reference: [Buildung Groovy Projects with GMaven](http://gmaven.codehaus.org/Building+Groovy+Projects)

**Update:**

> If i define a test to run, it run. but
>   with just mvn clean test, the test are
>   compiled, but not executed

This sounds like you're not following the naming conventions for test classes.

See the first section of this page: [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Comment: i follow your advices. But the result is the same. If i define a test to run, it run. but with just mvn clean test, the test are compiled, but not executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I didn't pay attention to it, cause i'm bringing this project from grails, wich use the pattern, <className>Tests.
The S was my mistake.